# How can I reset my windows 7 file permissions to a rational state?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I've messed up my file permissions on my home directory. Here's a small sampling of the output from [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332)

[image]

How can I fix this so that there's one set of rational permissions, that is

Read and Write for on c:\users\scott (recursively) for Administrators and my own account?

Command line solutions preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Give the Administrators group ownership of the directory...

```
TakeOwn.exe /f "C:\Users\Scott" /a /r /d y
```

Grant Administrators and Scott full control.

```
cacls.exe "C:\Users\Scott" /t /c /g Administrators:F
cacls.exe "C:\Users\Scott" /t /c /e /g Scott:F
```

Note the double quotes aren't necessary in this case. I do it out of habit.

**Update:** The line to give Administrators full control doesn't seem to be necessary. TakeOwn apparently does that while it's changing the ownership.

Comment: This helped, but isn't ideal as it sets explicit permissions on each object.

Comment: You could use icacls.exe instead. That is, remove the /t switches from the cacls commands above, so they don't process child items. Then do something like:  for /f %a in ('dir C:\Users\Scott /a-l /b') do @icacls "C:\Users\Scott\%a" /reset /t /l /c

Comment: @ScottWeinstein What would be better than setting explicit permissions on each object?

Comment: shouldn't subdirectories of a user's home be owned by that user?

Comment: I think what Scott was saying is that the folders and files inside the profile should inherit permissions from the root profile directory, rather than having explicit permissions set on them. In that case, you would use the icacls method in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had a variation on this problem: 3 files in a random directory were suddenly unavailable, couldn't be opened, deleted, or have their permissions changed.  Using a variation of Patrick S. response worked for me:

```
takeown /F "MyLockedFile"
icacls "MyLockedFile" /reset
```

Answer (score -2):

Do a repair install (inplace upgrade) of Windows. Make sure you back up first. Also, you will need to reinstall all updates and maybe some programs.

Comment: Doesn't this have a lot of side effects?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by side effects.

Comment: A side effect is an effect that is secondary to the one intended.

Comment: You will need to reinstall all updates and maybe some programs. Also, you’d better back up.

Comment: I'm looking for something way simpler and more targeted.

Comment: I always solved such problems in this way.

Comment: That doesn't make it the best solution, though. Burning down a house certainly gets rid of ants, but a more targeted solution would probably be best to try first.