# How do I restore default permissions for C:\Users?

Tags: windows, permissions

I recently messed up the permissions of my home folder (`c:\users\michal`). I took my laptop hard drive (Windows 10) into a USB external hard drive case. Then I mount the USB drive in another Windows 10. I browsed the users folder. Windows asked me to chaged the persmissions for `c:\users\michal` so that I could see what is in this folder. I agreed to do so. When I took back my HDD to my laptop Windows run but I am not able to run some programs, create, modify or delete some files. How do I set the correct permissions for my home folder?

**EDIT**

To take ownership, I used `TakeOwn.exe /f "C:\Users\michal" /a /r /d y` from built-in Administrator account but this produced the following error:

`ERROR: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`

My question is not a duplicate. The other questions deals with `Basically a while back I (very stupidly) changed the permissions on all sorts of system folders, and eventually rendered my computer virtually unusable.` My question deals **only** with a home folder. Guys, please me more accurate while arguing that a question is a duplicate.

@Ramhound has suggested using `icacls "c:/users/michal/*" /q /c /t /reset`

Unfortunetly, this won't work either. I get:

`Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 422 files`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset windows 7 file permissions?](http://superuser.com/questions/486885/how-can-i-reset-windows-7-file-permissions)

Comment: It is not  duplicate. See my updated question.

Comment: @menteith Can you acces the folder with admin rights? Did you already try the solution from the link Ramhound used for the possible duplicate?

Comment: Have you considered the `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose` as per **RamClown's** very first comment link and and the most voted for answer there? I wasn't sure 100% if it's applicable to Windows 10 or not but close enough for you to read up more about at least to confirm and consider testing, etc. Crack open the file `%windir%\inf\defltbase.inf` with a text editor such as Notepad and just look over its contents.

Comment: You might also look into using the [Last Known Good Configuration](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/restart-safe-mode/) just in case or perhaps look at one of the two options here [Restore from a restore point or reset this PC with "keep these files"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options).  I see one of those four things I mentioned including the one already mentioned by someone else as well as these three things as a FEW good starting points which you've NOT already tried based on your question. Report back your results afterwards.

Comment: @RamonRobben I tried his solution. I can access with admin rights.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicious I will try 'secedit` and post back its results.

Comment: Mento's the breath freshener... What was your outcome with the `SECEDIT` commands? Remember I mentioned three additional items to consider, etc. above as well should the `SECEDIT` command solution per Ramhound not suffice.

Comment: It did not work, either. I'm going to set up a new account and copy to it all files using `robocopy`.